# Z3-OPT binary files for the windows 64 bit machine

Tags: z3

I am trying to get Z3-OPT (optimization) binary files for the windows 64-bit machine. To make these files, I already tried to compile the code from the unstable branch. However, I could not compile them as my Visual Studio Community edition does not contain "nmake" command. I tried to follow instructions on the following page:

https://github.com/Z3Prover/z3

Can anyone share with me the latest Z3-OPT binary files?

Answer (score 2):

Z3-opt is now the same as Z3, so you can just use the main links for downloading Z3.
The releases are in: https://github.com/Z3Prover/bin/tree/master/releases
There is also a folder with nightly builds.

You have to enable C++ features in VS before you get the command line build tools. This involves *updating* the installation of VS itself, something you can do from "Apps and Features" (in Windows 10) or similar place in previous versions of Windows. There is already some online discussions about this question. For example, https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/39632/adding-nmake-to-vs2017.html.